# How to execute long running SQL statements in SQL Server with node

Tags: sql, sql-server, tedious

I got a big file contains with 10000 lines table rows data, and I had to insert it with a SQL method in my project, so I generated a very long SQL after parsing it. But it doesn't allow me to execute this at one time.

I think it should be placed in a transaction, and I got the way to use transaction with one short SQL in this [doc](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#transaction). What method should I use in its document?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you could process at SQL Server side using [Bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) or OLEDB

Comment: I tried Unix path on my mac but failed, is it only support windows path(start with ```c:\```)?